HTTP 403 error when trying to follow the "Vector search by using REST" guide by Azure
I was trying to follow this guide to learn how to use OpenAI embeddings using Azure AI search. I completed all the steps exactly as instructed but when I tried to create an index using the code below I kept getting HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error, even though all the proxy, firewall etc settings were fine.
@baseUrl = PUT-YOUR-SEARCH-SERVICE-URL-HERE
@token = PUT-YOUR-PERSONAL-IDENTITY-TOKEN-HER


### Create a new index
POST {{baseUrl}}/indexes?api-version=2023-11-01  HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json
    Authorization: Bearer {{token}}

{
    "name": "hotels-vector-quickstart",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "HotelId", 
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": false, 
            "filterable": true, 
            "retrievable": true, 
            "sortable": false, 
            "facetable": false,
            "key": true
        },
        {
            "name": "HotelName", 
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true, 
            "filterable": false, 
            "retrievable": true, 
            "sortable": true, 
            "facetable": false
        },
        {
            "name": "HotelNameVector",
            "type": "Collection(Edm.Single)",
            "searchable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "dimensions": 1536,
            "vectorSearchProfile": "my-vector-profile"
        },
        {
            "name": "Description", 
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true, 
            "filterable": false, 
            "retrievable": true, 
            "sortable": false, 
            "facetable": false
        },
        {
            "name": "DescriptionVector",
            "type": "Collection(Edm.Single)",
            "searchable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "dimensions": 1536,
            "vectorSearchProfile": "my-vector-profile"
        },
        {
            "name": "Category", 
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true, 
            "filterable": true, 
            "retrievable": true, 
            "sortable": true, 
            "facetable": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Tags",
            "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
            "searchable": true,
            "filterable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": false,
            "facetable": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Address", 
            "type": "Edm.ComplexType",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "City", "type": "Edm.String",
                    "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "retrievable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "StateProvince", "type": "Edm.String",
                    "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "retrievable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Location",
            "type": "Edm.GeographyPoint",
            "searchable": false, 
            "filterable": true, 
            "retrievable": true, 
            "sortable": true, 
            "facetable": false
        }
    ],
    "vectorSearch": {
        "algorithms": [
            {
                "name": "my-hnsw-vector-config-1",
                "kind": "hnsw",
                "hnswParameters": 
                {
                    "m": 4,
                    "efConstruction": 400,
                    "efSearch": 500,
                    "metric": "cosine"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "my-hnsw-vector-config-2",
                "kind": "hnsw",
                "hnswParameters": 
                {
                    "m": 4,
                    "metric": "euclidean"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "my-eknn-vector-config",
                "kind": "exhaustiveKnn",
                "exhaustiveKnnParameters": 
                {
                    "metric": "cosine"
                }
            }
        ],
        "profiles": [      
            {
                "name": "my-vector-profile",
                "algorithm": "my-hnsw-vector-config-1"
            }
      ]
    },
    "semantic": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "my-semantic-config",
                "prioritizedFields": {
                    "titleField": {
                        "fieldName": "HotelName"
                    },
                    "prioritizedContentFields": [
                        { "fieldName": "Description" }
                    ],
                    "prioritizedKeywordsFields": [
                        { "fieldName": "Tags" }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}


It turns out that the example code will only work if you are using Azure Roles instead of API keys for authentication.
Therefore, for API keys case, the line
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}

in the code above should be changed to:
api-key: {{token}}


Nope, this code is working for both cases (Azure roles or API Key), but your Search Service not to be correctly set to accepted one, the other, or both authentication types. As detailed in the documentation you post, "Make sure your search service is configured for role-based access. ": I think you might have not set that

@NicolasR I might have missed something but the point is I tried using the search service without setting up roles and only using API keys, which should be fine - this is the default. The "make sure.." you quote is in the section for setting up roles - there is not requirement to set up roles for API key authentication of course. Nonetheless the code given in the Guide worked only when I set up roles. It still leaves open the possibility that you need some extra set up to make the API keys access work with the code above but does not change my point - i.e. the guide is incomplete.

Ok I got your point :) yes, in all the code steps in the guide, they should tell that it is using RBAC authentication
